# Difficulty requesting the Access Token With OAuth? Error: No token or token_secret

Tags: php, oauth

I'm hoping someone might be able to answer. I've been working on this for many hours and can't find the solution. I've also studied the HTTP_OAUTH [documentation](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_OAuth/docs/latest/__filesource/fsource_HTTP_OAuth__HTTP_OAuth-0.1.7HTTPOAuthConsumer.php.html) over and over as well as some tutorials. I'm stuck using that because my host doesn't support normal OAuth. That aside, it's not so bad. This is what I have so far. I'm able to:

1. Acquire an access token (URL_PATH_GOES_HERE?**oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX**)
2. Redirect the user to get their permission
3. Redirect back to my callback URL with an access token and oauth_verifier(URL_PATH_GOES_HERE?**oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX?oauth_verifier=XXXXXXXXXX**)

When I get there, however, I'm having difficulty requesting the Access Token so I can from there on out make requests on behalf of the user.

I keep getting the error:

> No token or token_secret

Any ideas? I'd be eternally grateful!!

```
##############################
## FILNENAME: msconfig.php ###
##############################

<?php
    define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY',CONSUMER KEY GOES HERE);
    define('OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET',CONSUMER SECRET GOES HERE);
    define('OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN_API', 'http://gomiso.com/oauth/request_token');
    define('OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_API', 'http://gomiso.com/oauth/authorize'); 
    define('OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_API', 'http://gomiso.com/oauth/access_token');
    define('CALLBACK_URL', 'URL_PATH_GOES_HERE/callback.php');
    define('MISO_USER_AGENT', 'youruseragent');
?>

###############################
### FILNENAME: index.php ######
###############################

<?php

    //##########################################################################
    // START A SESSION SO WE CAN SHARE VARIABLES WITH OUR CALLBACK HANDLER #####
    //##########################################################################
    session_start();

    //############################
    // IMPORT CONFIGURATION FLE ##
    //############################
    require_once("misoconfig.php");

    //##########################    
    //#IMPORT EXTERNAL CLASSES #
    //##########################
    require_once("HTTP/OAuth/Consumer.php");

    //########################
    //# FETCH REQUEST TOKEN ##
    //########################
    try { 
        $consumer = new HTTP_OAuth_Consumer(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        $consumer->getRequestToken(OAUTH_REQUEST_TOKEN_API,CALLBACK_URL);
        $_SESSION['request_token'] = $consumer->getToken();
    }catch (Exception $e) {     
        echo 'Fetching Request Token Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n"; 
    } 

    //#############################################     
    // REDIRECT THE USER TO THE AUTHORIZATION URL #
    //#############################################
    try { 
        $url = $consumer->getAuthorizeUrl(OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_API);
        header("Location: $url");
    }catch (Exception $e) {     
        echo 'Authorization URL Redirection Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n"; 
    } 

?>

##############################
## FILNENAME: callback.php ###
##############################

<?php

    // START A SESSION SO WE CAN ACCESS VARIABLES SHARED WITH US BY INDEX.PHP 
    session_start();

    // IMPORT CONFIGURATION FLE 
    require_once("misoconfig.php");

    // IMPORT EXTERNAL CLASSES
    require_once("HTTP/OAuth/Consumer.php");

     // Store these tokens (at least for now)
        $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']   = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];

    // BY REACHING THIS FAR, WE'VE BEEN AUTHENTICATED. LET'S GRAB THE ACCESS TOKEN AND SECRET AND SAVE THEM <SOMEWHRE>. 
    try { 
        $consumer = new HTTP_OAuth_Consumer($_SESSION['request_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']);
        $consumer->getAccessToken(OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_API,$_SESSION['oauth_verifier'],array(),'GET');
    }catch (Exception $e) { 
        echo 'Access Token Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n"; 
    } 

?>
```

Comment: I took the liberty of editing you title since the on propose was not very descriptive of the problem and too general, feel free to improve my version in whatever way you feel like but I would suggest a tittle as specific as possible.

Comment: @Trufa: Thanks a bunch! That looks much better actually!

Comment: no problem, no idea on your question though but good luck!

Comment: haha, it's so annoying. there's basically three steps to OAuth and I'm on the very last one and I can't get it work! UGHH!!

Answer (score 0):

On your index.php file:

```
$_SESSION['request_token']        = $consumer->getToken();
$_SESSION['request_token_secret'] = $consumer->getTokenSecret();
```

On the callback.php file:

```
$consumer = new HTTP_OAuth_Consumer(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['request_token'], $_SESSION['request_token_secret']);
$consumer->getAccessToken(OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_API,$_SESSION['oauth_verifier'],array(),'GET');
# and save the new tokens after
$_SESSION['request_token']        = $consumer->getToken();
$_SESSION['request_token_secret'] = $consumer->getTokenSecret();
```

Comment: No luck! I still get 401'd. 

I kept index.php the same (I think that's what you wanted me to do) and I signed my consumer now looks like this:

$consumer = new HTTP_OAuth_Consumer($_SESSION['request_token'], $_SESSION['request_token_secret']);

i'm doing a try and catch and everytime, the error it spits out is:

No token or token_secret

Comment: You have to modify index.php, to set the $_SESSION['request_token_secret']

Comment: @paul-calabro I forgot to set the consumer keys, my bad, in instantiating the consumer object. I edited it to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed the callback.php file a bit to match the example and now it seemed to work. Do let me know if it works for you but for me I am getting back the correct response.

```
<?php

// START A SESSION SO WE CAN ACCESS VARIABLES SHARED WITH US BY INDEX.PHP
session_start();

// IMPORT CONFIGURATION FLE
require_once("misoconfig.php");

// IMPORT EXTERNAL CLASSES
require_once("HTTP/OAuth/Consumer.php");

 // Store these tokens (at least for now)
    $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']   = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];

try {
    // !!!CHANGED ARGUMENTS TO MATCH EXAMPLE
    $consumer = new HTTP_OAuth_Consumer(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['request_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_verifier']);
    $consumer->getAccessToken(OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_API, $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'],array(),'POST');
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Access Token Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

?>
```

By the way, I know it's a lot of work but can you create a github repo for the sample after it works. I would like to be able to link to the example for other user's future reference. If not that's fine.